# What resources are there for connecting engines to play automatically on remote servers?

Tags: software

What resources are there, e.g. tutorials, for connecting engines to play automatically on remote servers such as ICC?  There are certain opening variations that I want to have a strong engine test and refine on a significant basis.  Modifying an engines book is another matter, though material on that would be nice.

But the material I find, either on engines and interfaces themselves, or on automating engines to play on ICC, is either piecemeal, or far from comprehensive.  [This link](http://www.horizonchess.com/FAQ/Winboard/Winboard2.html#%5BB.3%5D) is the best I can do, and as you can see, it in turn refers you to other material.  But I'm concerned about how up to date this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinBoard is the way to go, also check out...

http://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html

http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/

The WinBoard forum is probably the best place to ask this question or the answer can be found there.

Comment: http://www.chessclub.com/help/xboard